# Why I get segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c99

Hi I don't know why I get the segmentation fault error. I have to, given the pointer to a file (which contains one number per line, like 12232 in the first line and 240 in the second etc..) I have to find and print for each number the cipher that is repeated more in time in the number, line in 12232 it should printf: "the number is 12232 nad the number is 2"

```
void stampa(FILE *fp) {

    char m[MAX], copia[MAX], *fp_m = m;
    int rip, dim, i, j, massimo=0, valore;

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Puntatore a file vuoto.");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(!(feof(fp))){
        fgets(m, MAX, fp);
        fp_m = m;
        dim = strlen(m)-1;
        for (i=0; i < dim; i++){
            copia[i] = fp_m[i];
        }
        copia[i] = '\0';

        for(i=0; copia[i]!='\0'; i++){
            rip = 0;
            if (copia[i] == '*')
                i++;
            else{
                for(j=i; j < dim; j++){
                    if(fp_m[i] == copia[j]){
                        rip++;
                        copia[j] = '*';
                    }
                }
                if (rip == massimo && fp_m[i] > fp_m[valore])
                    valore = i;
                if(rip > massimo){
                    massimo = rip;
                    valore = i;
                }
            }

        }
        massimo = 0;
        printf("Il numero piu' ripetuto in %s e': %c \n", m, fp_m[valore]);
    }

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Break out your debugger.  On what line does the segfault occur?  What are the values of all your variables when it happens?

Comment: I think to have understood the problem but I cannot understand why.. I have solved it by using a pointer to the array 'm' and if i use that pointer in all the function all works good, may I know why?

Comment: Yes I solved that problem just defining a char pointer to that char array and it worked, may i know why I couldn't modify the array directly?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation as to what you changed - could you show the new code?  Unfortunately, by the nature of C, it's quite possible that the code is still incorrect and just happens to work now by chance.

Comment: done, i have posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of bugs:

1. `while(!(feof(fp))){` [is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/634919).
2. ```
   for(i=0; copia[i]!='\0'; i++){
       rip = 0;
       if (copia[i] == '*')
           i++;
   ```

   When `copia[i]=='*'` then `i` will be incremented once in the `if` clause and again at the end of the loop.  This will skip a character following the `*`. In particular, if the string ends in `'*'` then you will skip over the trailing null byte and start operating on uninitialized memory.  You most likely just wanted to do nothing (or possibly `continue;`) when `copia[i]=='*'`.

Adding the `fp_m` pointer didn't make this bug any better or worse, but changing the layout of the stack may have caused the loop to eventually run into a null byte and terminate instead of crashing.  That's actually a bad thing, because it made you think the bug was gone when it wasn't.  Making unrelated changes until your program runs is an extremely bad habit when programming in C.